# Simple "catching" logic

Tags: c++, exception, c++-cli, try-catch

I have a string^ that's being converted to a Uint32 In the code below:

```
try
{
    int newX = System::Convert::ToUInt32(this->cbXSizeBox->Text);
}
catch (FormatException^ e)
{
    printf("\nNot a valid 3-digit number");
    this->cbXSizeBox->Text = System::Convert::ToString(capBoxSize->x);
}
```

This works fine.(FYI capBoxSize->x is another value that can evaluate to uint32).

Basically the catch is to snap the value of cbXSizeBox->Text (which is a string), back to it's default value, should the user enter anything but numbers (e.g. 2g9).

In the event that the catch block doesn't catch a format exception, I would like to add code to change the value of capBoxSize->x to it's new valid value. I'm trying to find something that says to the compiler, "if you catch this exception, do this. But If you don't catch the exception, do this." Is it possible to wrap a catch block in an if else statement?

If you understand what I'm trying to do, any suggestions would be appreciated.

P.S. Putting the code to change capBoxSize->x in the try block isn't really an option I think. As this could attempt assigning newX as something like "2ty" to  capBoxSize->X, which is a Uint32. Which may cause errors.

Comment: Please use the `c++-cli` tag when asking about C++/CLI.

Comment: apologies, I'll correct it.

Comment: np, I already edited it in. It was just for the future. C++/CLI is a different langauge than C++.

Comment: Could you explain your p.s. more clearly.  In an example perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for an `else` block, just put the formatting after the actual parsing:

```
try {
    int newX = System::Convert::ToUInt32(this->cbXSizeBox->Text);
    capBoxSize->x = newX;
}
catch (FormatException^ e) {
    printf("\nNot a valid 3-digit number");
    this->cbXSizeBox->Text = System::Convert::ToString(capBoxSize->x);
}
```

Actually there’s no need for the temporary `newX`, just assign it directly:

```
capBoxSize->x = System::Convert::ToUInt32(this->cbXSizeBox->Text);
```

> Putting the code to change capBoxSize->x in the try block isn't really an option I think. As this could attempt assigning newX as something like "2ty" to capBoxSize->X, which is a Uint32.

That will never happen because at this point your code has already thrown an exception and has consequently left the `try` block and entered the `catch` block.

---

That said, I would avoid `try…catch` here and use `System::Int32::TryParse` instead.

Comment: This is what I would say but the OP said it wasn't an option, which I don't understand.

Comment: @Adrian It’s simple: OP is simply wrong. ;-) It happens to all of us.

Comment: That would explain why I didn't understand it. :) :D

Comment: I'll attempt to explain my mistake. I think what I was confused about (and was corrected with this answer) was that the moment an exception is thrown at runtime, the program "breaks out" of the try block at that very line, without executing any more of the try block, jumping into the catch block. Now I know. And knowing is half the battle! :D

Comment: Yes, this is different from Windows's Structured Exception Handling, which gives a chance to return right at the offending statement if the filter returns `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`.

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines of:

```
bool exception_caught = false;
try {
    int newX = System::Convert::ToUInt32(this->cbXSizeBox->Text);
} catch (FormatException ^e) {
    //  Format exception code.
    exception_caught = true;
    // Handle Exception stuff
}

if (!exception_caught) {
    //  Other stuff.
}
```

Comment: I was thinking this, but why is the OP asking for this?  I don't understand the P.S.

Comment: I'm not sure, I know that sometimes I make things over complex when I'm too focused on the problem.